# Highcharts Stock update first value to 0 after zoom or setExtremes

Tags: highcharts, stock

I have two series that start with value 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubO84.jpg)

When I modify the zoom I need the initial value of that view to change to 0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI0WD.jpg)

If the zoom is modified again, all the values ​​that would have been modified to 0 return to their original value, and the new view should again start at 0.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setExtremes` event callback and update points according to their position. For example:

```
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      setExtremes: function(e) {
        this.series.forEach(s => {
          const firstPoint = s.points.find(p => p.isInside);
          const lastModifiedPoint = s.points.find(
            p => p.originalValue || p.originalValue === 0
          );

          if (firstPoint.y !== 0) {
            firstPoint.originalValue = firstPoint.y;
            firstPoint.update({
              y: 0
            }, false);
          }

          if (lastModifiedPoint && lastModifiedPoint !== firstPoint) {
            lastModifiedPoint.update({
              y: lastModifiedPoint.originalValue
            }, false);

            delete lastModifiedPoint.originalValue;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d19fw7zL/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.setExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update